# mySQL query to select on the max value of one field  with another field common

Tags: mysql

1I am trying to write a message table with conversation threads like gmail. (I use php). The table is as shown. posID means the position of each message in a given threadID.

```
id | senderID | recvrID |  message(threadID,posID)  | threadID | posID |   time 
1       1          3            msg 1,1                  1          1       12pm
2       3          1            msg 1,2                  1          2        3pm
3       1          2            msg 2,1                  2          1        1pm
```

I need to write a query to find all msg threads to senderID=1 (in this case), and if there are more than one msgs in a thread, select the last msg only in each thread (can sort by positionID or time).

expected output is a table as follows.

```
 senderID      |  message                 | Time
   1               msg 1,2                  3pm
   1               msg 2,1                   1pm
```

Edit:
After more reading, I guess I need to select messages with the sender/ receiver constraints, AND ( if more than one messages in a thread, only those messages with MAX(posID) for each threadID). Dont know how to implement this.

Comment: share the result you want in tabular format.

Comment: output is a table as follows.
______________________________________________________
senderID     |  message                      | Time
______________________________________________________
   1               msg 1,2                        12pm
   1               msg 2,1                         1pm

Comment: @Romil I have updated the question with the expected output.

Comment: If you sort by `posID`, latest message is the on at `3pm`, while in your sample it is the one from `12pm`. So what is the right ordering?

Comment: I think these questions will be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is misleading:

- you actually need all threads where `userID=1` is either sender or receiver;
- for `threadID=1` and `posID=2` corresponding time is `3pm`, but not `12pm` as you've specified.

The following query will give you the last message in each thread by it's position:

```sql
SELECT senderID, recvrID, message, time
  FROM message m
  JOIN (SELECT threadID,max(posID) maxPOS FROM message
        GROUP BY threadID) mm
    ON m.threadID = mm.threadID AND m.posID = mm.maxPOS;
```

You can add the following filters:

- `WHERE senderID=1` for messages where `userID=1` is only a sender. *This will not match your sample though*;
- `WHERE senderID=1 OR recvrID=1` for all messages, where `userID=1` is participating. *This will produce the expected results.*

Try out the query [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17464/18).

Note, that your table will not be able to handle cases where one message has multiple recipients.

Comment: To @vyegorov, your solution worked. Sorry my question had some misleading data in te expected output section. you are right about the time for msg 1,2 (3 pm) and i have updated it. Also, this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4713912/903978) with some modification gets the same results. And in my application, there are no multiple recepients, so that should be all right. Thanks –

Comment: To @vyegorov, Can you help me with this? I am using this query

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mail INNER JOIN (SELECT threadID,MAX(time) as time FROM mail WHERE recipientID = "$id"  GROUP by threadID ) Latest ON mail.threadID=Latest.threadID AND mail.time=Latest.time

But this brings out the results with the newest dated messages at the bottom. Do you know how to sort the selection by time (NEWEST first).

Comment: @aVC, contact me over Skype, same nickname.

Comment: i sent a msg on skype,says it delivery pending.

Comment: Can you offer some hint on this one?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928108/mysql-query-within-a-query-with-privacy-condition-check

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$user = '1';
$q="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE senderID = '$user'";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($w=mysql_fetch_array($r)){    
   $thread = $w['threadID'];
   $id = $w['id'];
   $message = $w['message'];
   $q2="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE threadID = '$thread'".
        "ORDER BY posID DESC LIMIT 1";   
   $r2=mysql_query($q2);
   while($w2=mysql_fetch_array($r2)){
      $checkid = $w2['id'];
      if($checkid != $id){
         $message = $w2['message'];
      }
   }
   echo $message;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it brings only one message, even when there are more than one threadIDs.