# mysql query within a query with privacy condition check

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables.

```
myMembers
------------------------------------
id | username | privacy
------------------------------------
1  | userA    | 0
2  | userB    | 1
3  | userC    | 0
4  | userD    | 1

following
--------------------------------
id  | user_id  | follower_id
--------------------------------
1   | 2        | 1

posts
-------------------------------------
id  |  userID | username   | statusMsg
--------------------------------------
1   |  4      | userD    | Issac Newton is genius
2   |  2      | userB    | Newton Saw apple
3   |  3      | userC    | Newtonian Physics
4   |  1      | userA    | Calculus came from Sir Newton
```

There is a search field. When a logged in user searches for 'keyword' in table 'posts', I want to omit results from those users who has set his privacy to '1'  and WHERE searcher is not following user B.

The query should logically do this.

```
SELECT * from posts WHERE (match the keyword) 
            AND ( 
                if (poster's privacy (which is set in myMembers)==1){
                    if (seacher is following poster){
                        select this post
                    }
                }
                   else { select this post
                }
             )
                   LIMIT results to 5 rows
```

So for a keyword "Newton",
if userA is searching, rows 2,3,4 from 'posts' should be returned.
if userD is searching, only rows 1, 3 and 4 from 'posts' should be returned,

based on privacy and following
Edit: Tagging for future searches: IF condition within WHERE Clause in mySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this query (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48b44/3)):

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, m.username, m.privacy,
       searcher.username "Searcher", p.status_msg
  FROM posts p
  JOIN members m ON m.id = p.user_id
  LEFT JOIN following f ON p.user_id = f.user_id
  JOIN members searcher ON searcher.username = 'userA'
 WHERE (m.privacy = 0 OR (m.privacy = 1 AND f.follower_id = searcher.id)
                      OR m.id = searcher.id)
   AND p.status_msg LIKE '%New%'
 ORDER BY p.id
 LIMIT 5;
```

I removed `username` field from `posts` table, as it is redundant. Also, I named tables and columns slightly different, so query might need cosmetic changes for your schema.

The first line in the `WHERE` clause is the one that you're looking for, it selects posts in the following order:

1. First posts from members without privacy;
2. Then posts from members that are followed by the current `searcher`;
3. Finally, posts of the member himself.

---

**EDIT:**

This query is using original identifiers:

```
SELECT p.id, p.`userID`, m.username, m.privacy,
       searcher.username "Searcher", p.`statusMsg`
  FROM posts p
  JOIN `myMembers` m ON m.id = p.`userID`
  LEFT JOIN following f ON p.`userID` = f.user_id
  JOIN `myMembers` searcher ON searcher.username = 'userD'
 WHERE (m.privacy = 0 OR f.follower_id = searcher.id OR m.id = searcher.id)
   AND p.`statusMsg` LIKE '%New%'
 ORDER BY p.id
 LIMIT 5;
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

To avoid duplicates in case there're several followers for the user from the `posts` table, join and filtering conditions should be changed the following way (on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6262/31)):

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, m.username, m.privacy,
       searcher.username "Searcher", p.status_msg
  FROM posts p
  JOIN members m ON m.id = p.user_id
  JOIN members searcher ON searcher.username = 'userC'
  LEFT JOIN following f ON p.user_id = f.user_id
   AND follower_id = searcher.id
 WHERE (m.privacy = 0 OR (m.privacy = 1 AND f.id IS NOT NULL)
                      OR m.id = searcher.id)  
 ORDER BY p.id
 LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to not load (I tried on two machines) and different browsers (moz and chrome). I will try query on my localhost soon anyways and keep you updated. Thanks a lot

Comment: @aVC - sqlfiddle was having some drive space issues.  It is working now.

Comment: @aVC, SQL Fiddle working (quite slow though), so I added query with your original identifiers.

Comment: @vyegorov Thanks WHERE recipient=vyegorov LIMIT none ;)

Comment: @vyegorov Trying to understand the query, in the line with WHERE <>,  is n't m.id and searcher.id the same? both are myMembers table, correct? Also, in your Edited part with original identifiers, did you omit the m.privacy=1 part intentionally?

Comment: @JakeFeasel Thanks for the note I can see the fiddle now

Comment: @aVC, `m.id` and `searcher.id` are different. I'm using the same table twice with different names, so DB will see it as 2 different relations. And yes, I omitted `m.privacy=1` as it is redundant: second and third parts of the OR-ed condition will be checked _only_ if `m.privacy` <> 0.

Comment: @vyegorov I think I found a small problem. Can you see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6262/1 and run the query? I added 2 more rows into following  and the result gets duplicated.

Comment: @vyegorov Thanks. Seems good!!!! Looking at your queries, and from Omesh, I am rewriting a truck load of my queries. I did nt know of joins and used to do subqueries for each query result :) Appreciate more that you explain the details!

Comment: @vyegorov Can you kindly help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508674/limiting-mysql-results-by-range-of-a-specific-key-including-duplicates The query I have is actually yours :) long back.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM posts a
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id
                FROM following a1
                     INNER JOIN myMembers b1
                       ON a1.follower_id = b1.id
                  WHERE a1.follower_id = 1 AND
                        b1.privacy = 1
                ) b
                ON a.userID = b.user_id AND
WHERE a.statusMsg LIKE '%search%' AND
      b.user_id IS NULL
LIMIT 5;
```

or better approach without subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM posts a
     LEFT JOIN myMembers b
         ON a.userID = b.id AND
            b.privacy = 1
     LEFT JOIN following c
         ON a.userID = c.user_id AND
            c.follower_id = 1
WHERE a.statusMsg LIKE '%search%' AND
      b.id IS NULL AND
      c.user_id IS NULL
LIMIT 5;
```

See: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: lol this is like reading arabic as far as my SQL provess goes. :) Let me try it

Comment: I tried this. No results returned. To clarify, I updated the question

Comment: thanks for that visual explanation link. Let me try to understand your query in the meantime. :)

Comment: you're welcome. simplified my query. you need to substitute 'A' with userID variables and '%search%' with your search term.

Comment: Thanks. Just from a look, will it include  results if userID in posts have set their privacy=0 in myMembers?

Comment: thats the problem. query should return all posts, unless user B  has set privacy =1 in myMembers and userA who is searching is not following userB. I think there has to be an IF in the query somewhere.

Can you see the "IF" section in the question? :)

Comment: true, but then it will only bring those with privacy =0, even if searcher is following the poster. Any way to combine both cases?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15250/discussion-between-omesh-and-avc)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs yesterday. I got helped out by vyegorov :) Appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SET @my_user_id= 1;

SELECT * FROM posts p
INNER JOIN myMembers m ON p.user_id= m.id  
WHERE statusMsg LIKE '%'
AND privacy=0
AND user_id IN (SELECT follower_id FROM following f WHERE f.user_id=@my_user_id)
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @c 2 Query should get all rows in posts (where the poster's privacy = 0 as well as 1), but omit when privacy of poster=1 and searcher is not following the poster.