# limiting mysql results by range of a specific key INCLUDING DUPLICATES

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT p.*, m.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM newPhotoonAlert n WHERE n.userIDfor='$id' AND n.threadID=p.threadID and n.seen='0')  AS unReadCount 
    FROM posts p
    JOIN myMembers m ON m.id = p.user_id
    LEFT JOIN following f 
    ON (p.user_id = f.user_id AND f.follower_id='$id' 
    AND f.request='0' AND f.status='1')
    JOIN myMembers searcher ON searcher.id = '$id' 
    WHERE ((f.follower_id = searcher.id) OR m.id='$id')
    AND p.flagged <'5' 
    ORDER BY p.threadID DESC,p.positionID
```

It brings result as expected but I want to add Another CLAUSE to limit the results.
Say a sample (minimal shown) set of data looks like this with the above query.

```
threadID   postID positionID  url
  564       1254     2         a.com
  564       1245     1         a1.com
  541       1215     3         b1.com 
  541       1212     2         b2.com 
  541       1210     1         b3.com 
  523       745      1         c1.com
  435       689      2         d2.com
  435       688      1         a4.com
  256       345      1         s3.com
  164       316      1         f1.com
  .
  .
```

I want to get ROWS corresponding to 2  DISTINCT threadIDs starting from MAX, but I want to include duplicates as well.

Something like

```
AND p.threadID IN (Select just Two of all threadIDs currently selected, but include duplicate rows)
```

So my result should be

```
threadID   postID positionID  url
  564       1254     2         a.com
  564       1245     1         a1.com
  541       1215     3         b1.com 
  541       1212     2         b2.com 
  541       1210     1         b3.com
```

Comment: at first sort, then limit 10.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I cannot limit, because depending on duplicates, It may have more than ten. I want to LIMIT the threadID so that rows with 10 unique threadIDs can be retrieved. This may mean more than 10 rows if there are more than one rows with same threadID.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh His requirement is to select 10 distinct thread_id's but show all duplicates too that in turn may result in more than 10 tuples hence limit 10 will not be enough. He will need a **subquery** too.

Comment: @aVC check my answer. This should be the structure of your code.

Comment: Could you kindly describe your schema? From which table `threadID` is coming and how that table relates to others?

Comment: @vyegorov there are three seperate tables. myMembers, posts, following. I have created a sample here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a51a4.

Comment: @aVC, thanks for the sample, but could you kindly also (1) include the above mentioned rows (with all those urls) into the sample and (2) provide the “original” query in such a way, that it returns some sensible data based on your sample. Right now your query referencing non-existing table `newPhotoonAlert` and also references PHP variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
select threadID, postID, positionID, url 
from your_table where 
threadID in
(select * from (select distinct threadID from your_table order by threadID desc limit 10) as tab_alias);
```

Try this syntax to implement it.

Comment: thanks, I am not sure if I can simply use the (select disctint....)  because the choice of threadIDs is not straight forward. My question is, "Of the selected threadIDs, how can I pick a range? or is that not how you do it? Sorry I am not well versed with mysql and this query was not written by me.

Comment: @avc anyhow 1st you need to select `distinct threadid`s from a sorted descending order of `threadid`. Then you can select all the tuples from your table containing any of those distinct `threadIds` and hence all duplicates will also be selected. That's my answer.

Comment: @aVC, please, precise what you mean by `selected threadIDs` that needs to be limited. Is it (1) a list of 10 distinct IDs as @Rajesh outlined or (2) a list of IDs that are returned by your original query?

Comment: @vyegorov I have edited the question to show what I am getting now, and what I would like to get. In the question, I have changed 10 results to 2 results, to keep the question shorter.

Comment: @RajeshPaul thanks, Unfortunately, your query is showing me "#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery". I checked with my phpmyadmin and it says cpsrvd 11.36.2.4
Database client version: libmysql - 5.0.96

Comment: @aVC That's true. This is a limitation with **MySQL** itself. Just tried to solve it in a conventional way. Should have worked in another DBMS.

Comment: @RajeshPaul OK I am limited by it because of the hosting service. :( but i hope there is a way in mySQL. I am trying with my limited knowledge as well :)

Comment: @RajeshPaul IT did not work. Reason being, the way you are selecting the threadIDs totally fails the Query prior to that, so Zero results are returned.

Comment: @aVC Can't say what's wrong with your SQL but the sample code, I have given eliminates the mysql error. Try recoding in the same logic.

Comment: @RajeshPaul your query has no errors. Just that it does not return any rows. Because, the threadIDs have to be among the ones that are selected using the above query. I cant simply select threadIDs without the constraints in an inner query. That is the reason. :)